# Cross Browser Compatibility and docType declaration

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser

I designed a webpage and tested it on `firefox, chrome & IE-8`. The webpage is displayed fine on `firefox & chrome` but not on IE. 
In the process of making it compatible, I changed the DocType declaration from `HTML 4.01 Transitional` to `XHTML 1.1` to `HTML 4.01 Strict`. This failed to fix the cross compatability. Also, I found that the webpage design is messed up on `firefox & chrome` when I change the DocType from `HTML 4.01 Transitional` to `XHTML 1.1`.

Now my question is, if DocType does matter in designing webpages, which one should I use for cross compatibilty? Is there another solution that does not involve DocType?

Comment: Strict Doctype is the way to go, IE behaves better with it. Any examples of what is broken when you switch to strict doctype?

Comment: `Horizontal menu bar` is in top and `side bar` is just below the menubar. when i changed the docType then `sidebar` breaks & switched to beside of MenuBar and other `div`elements randomly rearranged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're only changing the DOCTYPE, but not changing any HTML or CSS.  This is something you'll need to do since each DOCTYPE will be rendered differently.

I recommend one of the STRICT ones - HTML4.01 STRICT, XHTML1.0 STRICT, or XHTML1.1, depending on your needs.  Or HTML5 (although I haven't used it yet myself).  Also, make sure you've got the doctype declaration correct and have included the xmlns in the html tag if you're using XHTML.

For reference:

- [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) has a lot a great information, including browser
  compatibility info.
- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) also has really helpful
  articles.
- I refer to the [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) and [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) Specifications
  often.

And to check your doctypes:

HTML 4.01 Strict, Transitional, Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

XHTML 1.0 Strict, Transitional, Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```

XHTML 1.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: The horizontal menu / sidebar issue sounds like it may be related to float/clear, and possibly display:block/inline/inline-block, which definitely has differences in rendering.

Comment: Thanks eric ! i'll try now and lets see how is it going.

Comment: can you post the html & css? it would really help.

Comment: ok, well, if the menu and the sidebar are both DIVs with display:block, and menu is float:left, sidebar may need a clear:left or clear:both to prevent it from moving up to the menu line.